# How do you not send a message to yourself in a multi chat server?

Tags: java

I have a multi client chat server and when someone sends a message i want it to go to all the other clients but not the one sending the message. Currently the message is being send to everyone including the person that sent the message? The code can be found below for the clientThread.java file.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClientThread extends Thread {

    Socket socket;
    String clientName;
    BufferedReader inputStream;
    PrintWriter outputStream;
    JLabel connectionStatusLabel;

    public ClientThread(Socket socket, JLabel connectionStatusLabel) {
        try {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.connectionStatusLabel = connectionStatusLabel;
            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            while (true) {
                String clientMessage = inputStream.readLine();
                if (clientMessage.equals("remove")) {
                    Server.clientsList.remove(this);
                    this.socket.close();
                    for (ClientThread clientThread : Server.clientsList) {
                        clientThread.outputStream.println(clientName+" is disconnected");
                        clientThread.outputStream.flush();
                    }
                } else if (clientMessage.equals("client_name")) {
                    clientName = inputStream.readLine();
                    for (ClientThread clientThread : Server.clientsList) {
                        clientThread.outputStream.println(clientName+" is connected");
                        clientThread.outputStream.flush();
                    }
                } else if (clientMessage.equals("message_broadcast")) {
                    String message = inputStream.readLine();
                    for (ClientThread clientThread : Server.clientsList) {
                        clientThread.outputStream.println(clientName + ": " + message);
                        clientThread.outputStream.flush();
                    }

                } else if (clientMessage.equals("message_single")) {
                    String messageTo = inputStream.readLine();
                    String message = inputStream.readLine();
                    for (ClientThread clientThread : Server.clientsList) {
                        if (clientThread.clientName.equals(messageTo)) {
                            clientThread.outputStream.println(clientName + ": " + message);
                            clientThread.outputStream.flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check to see if the the current instance from the `for` loop is not the same as the instance you're in?

```
            } else if (clientMessage.equals("message_broadcast")) {
                String message = inputStream.readLine();
                for (ClientThread clientThread : Server.clientsList) {
                    if (clientThread != this) {
                        clientThread.outputStream.println(clientName + ": " + message);
                        clientThread.outputStream.flush();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: awesome, nice job